# How can I export a model with a normal map

Tags: normal-map

I'm trying to export a tire wall which has a normal map on it, but whenever I export it and open it on another program like 3D viewer for example it the normal map is not visible. Is it possible to fix this?

[image: Tire wall on Blender]

[image: Tire wall on 3D viewer]

Answer (score 0):

## INFORMATION

---

Use the <kbd>glTF</kbd> exporter for Blender to 3D Viewer previewing.
**Note:** All of the exported meshes must be UV unwrapped + have UV nodes' attached to each materials' and material textures'.

## PROCESS

---

### Blender (2.7x)

The process shown in the screenshot can be accomplished in any version of Blender.

[image]

### 3D Viewer

3D Viewer should automatically show all material attributes (albedo, normal, roughness, metalic, AO, etc) or you can limit viewing of certain attributes in the software.

[image]

## DOWNLOAD

---

### (2.7x)

https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/releases/tag/2.79

### (+2.8x)

- Blender already comes pre-installed with it
- If you broke it: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO

Comment: Thanks but could you be a bit more specific on what I have to do, Sorry I'm kinda new to this stuff. Really appreciate it

Comment: Re-edited my post to better explain the required process.

Comment: As he said, just export as gITF(instead of .obj or .fbx), and it will export the normal map as well if you click the "tangent" checkbox under geometry.