# Unable to export normal map to GLTF

Tags: gltf

I am trying to export a simple gltf model to test how bump mapping looks in my engine. I followed [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227143/how-can-i-export-a-model-with-a-normal-map) link but nothing I do seems to be working. The exported model always has dark spots and looks pretty bad. What exactly is the process to export normal map from blender to gltf?[image]
[image]

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues, try using Non Color Space instead of sRGB Color space in the Bump texture node, keep Distance to 1.0 in the bump node and adjust the strenght as needed. Try also  baking a normal map inside Blender and use it with a Normal Map node instead of the Bump node (always use Non Color Space). If the problem persist, please upload your file.

Comment: I started from scratch and used Non Color and normal map node instead of bump and it looks good now. I have a specific normal texture I want to use so baking doesn't really apply to my situation. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong node "Bump" instead of "Normal Map" for glTF export.  The glTF format only accepts a Tangent-Space Normal Map, not general bump maps, for rendering efficiency.  If your image is greyscale (a heightmap), you'll need to convert it to a normal map as well.  The color space of that image should be set to non-color.

This is described in more detail in the Blender Manual's [glTF Export section](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#normal-map).

[image: node screenshot]